# pandas Interval not working with datetime objects

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Pandas Interval is throwing error with "datetime.datetime" objects but it works fine with "pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp" :

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd

t1 = datetime.now()
t2 = t1 + timedelta(hours = 1)
interval = pd.Interval(t1, t2) #this throws error
```

[image]

But this code works fine:

```
t1 = pd.Timestamp.now()
t2 = t1 + timedelta(hours = 1)
interval = pd.Interval(t1, t2)
```

Is pandas Interval designed to work with pandas Timestamp only and not with datetime?

Comment: Yes because python datetime and pandas datetime have different implementations, but is that an issue? Note that in the first case t1 and t2 can always be converted to pandas via `to_datetime`.

Comment: No issues yet, but my worry is with pandas datetime, to_datetime, etc. being deprecated,  will it continue to work in future.

Comment: IMO I don't believe this is a practical concern right now. pd.datetime is very much an integral part of the api and I don't see them removing that anytime soon. If and when they do there will be an ample deprecation period allowing you to migrate.